# Pass params to query in OpenQuery within table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, function, linked-server, openquery

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getTransactionBtwDateTime] (
    @start_date_time datetime,
    @end_date_time datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(My_LINKED_SERVER,'SELECT first_name, last_name, dob FROM employee WHERE dob between and ''' + @start_date_time + ''' and ''' + @end_date_time + ''')
GO
```

How can I pass 2 params above to openquery inside table-valued function?

Comment: "OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments." ref: [OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql) You would have to build a dynamic query to be run by `EXEC()` or `EXEC My_LINKED_SERVER.master.dbo.sp_executesql` if RPC access is permitted.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what is RPC you mean?

Comment: When [creating linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) you specify that they can be used for data access, RPC access (stored procedures) or both using [`sp_serveroption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-serveroption-transact-sql). RPC and RPC out are not enabled by default.